# Direct contour integration of the Riemann Zeta fuction at even natural numbers

Tags: contour-integration, riemann-zeta, mellin-transform

Is there a **direct** complex contour integral to evaluate 
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^3}{e^x-1}dx$$
WITHOUT expanding $\frac1{e^x-1}$ into a series then evaluating the infinite series $\displaystyle 3!\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^4}$.

Note: lease do **NOT** use the following series expression.

I know already by the Taylor series of $\frac1{1-u}$ for $|u|<1$, we have
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^3}{e^x-1}dx = \int_0^\infty x^3\sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-kx}dx = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_0^\infty x^3 e^{-kx}dx=3!\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{-4},$$
and then we can use contour integral to evaluate the last infinite series to obtain $\frac{\pi^4}{15}$. I do **NOT** want to use this series expression in the derivation.

In fact this is the Riemann Zeta function $\zeta(4)\Gamma(4).$

Answer (score -5):

Let [$f(z) = \frac{z}{e^z-1}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Generating_function). With the residue theorem
$$0 = \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{|z|=2\pi N+\pi} \frac{z^{-4}}{e^z-1}dz =  Res(\frac{z^{-4}}{e^z-1},0)+\sum_{k=-\infty,k\ne 0}^\infty Res(\frac{z^{-4}}{e^z-1},2i\pi k) \\=  \frac{f^{(4)}(0)}{4!} +\sum_{k=-\infty,k\ne 0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2i\pi k)^4} = \frac{-1}{4! \, 30}+ \zeta(4)2^{-3}\pi^{-4}$$

Qed
$$\zeta(4) = \frac{\pi^{4}}{90 }, \qquad 3!\zeta(4) = 3!\frac{\pi^{4}}{90 }= \int_0^\infty \frac{x^3}{e^x-1}dx$$

Comment: Good derivation, which I am already familiar with. However, if my understanding of your method is correct, you are taking exactly the approach I am trying to avoid as stated specifically in the question, because the way you arrive at $\zeta$ function is to expand $\frac1{e^x-1}$ and integrate term by term, then evaluate the series form of $\zeta$ by the residue theorem. You have actually stated the approach I described in the reverse order. I am asking to evaluate the integral form in a complex contour directly, without going through the intermediate step of infinite series expression.

Comment: @Hans You didn't state any approach and $\frac{1}{e^x-1}$ have many series expansion. Is your question about $\Gamma(4) \zeta(4) = \int_0^\infty \frac{x^3}{e^x-1}dx$ or $\zeta(4) = \frac{\pi^{4}}{90 }$ ? For obtaining the last one, there is no direct way from $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^3}{e^x-1}dx$

Comment: I did state what approach I did not want to take, if you read the clause "without expanding ... " in my original question. By "... have many series expansion" are you saying that the equality you established between $\frac1{\Gamma(4)}\int_0^\infty \frac{x^3}{e^x-1}dx=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^4}$ is not through expanding $\frac1{e^x-1}$ and integrate term by term? Well, of course, one can do this in a roundabout way but I think it is the most direct way. I am however curious what your way is to establish this equality without the expansion.

Comment: On the main topic, I would like to, as I have stated, apply the residue theorem via a contour integral circumventing the zeta function series expression. We probably will reach the same contour integral as you have stated in your answer, we both know. I would like to reach that contour integral and it being $\frac{\pi^4}{15}$ without the intermediate infinte series expression of the $\zeta$ function.

Comment: @Hans What you want is unclear. The residue theorem relates a contour integral $\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_\gamma g(z)dz$ to the sum of residues $\sum_{\rho \in \gamma} Res(g(z), \rho)$. Here $g(z) = \frac{z^{-4}}{e^z-1}$ and $Res(g(z), 2i \pi k) = \frac{1}{2^4 \pi^4 k^4} = \frac{1}{2^4 \pi^4 3!} \int_0^\infty x^3 e^{-kx}dx$

Comment: I just added a sentence in my question. Do you think it is clear?

Comment: @Hans Not really. Rephrasing my answer, by direct application of the residue theorem $$\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{|z|=2\pi N-\pi} \frac{z^{-4}}{e^z-1}dz = \frac{f^{(4)}(0)}{4!} +  \frac{2^{-3} \pi^{-4}}{3!} \int_0^\infty x^3 \frac{1-e^{-N x}}{e^x-1}dx$$ and hence  $$0 = \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{|z|=2\pi N-\pi} \frac{z^{-4}}{e^z-1}dz = \frac{f^{(4)}(0)}{4!} +  \frac{2^{-3} \pi^{-4}}{3!} \int_0^\infty \frac{x^3}{e^x-1}dx$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60473/discussion-between-hans-and-user1952009).

Comment: @Hans I wrote in my answer how I obtain this. I also used $$\sum_{k=1}^N k^{-4} = \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{3!}\int_0^\infty x^3 e^{-kx}dx = \frac{1}{3!} \int_0^\infty x^3 \frac{1-e^{-N x}}{e^x-1}dx$$

Comment: I was awaiting your response in the chat room, but none came. I was saying your response stating you are using $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^4}$ seems to contradict what I have requested specifically in my question which is **NOT** to use $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^4}$. Could you please explain the apparent contradiction? If you indeed have not used the infinite series, how do you establish your first equation in your second last comment without it?

Comment: @Hans It is not obvious if you understand everything I wrote. And it is 100% clear you can't explain what you want. See your comments : no formulas, I'm doing all the job. So maybe you need to work on what I wrote instead ?

Comment: I understand everything you have written. Could you please read my original question again? Also, could you please just answer me one question with a yes or no? Have you used $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^3}{e^x-1}dx=3!\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^4}$ in your intermediate step in your derivation?

Comment: Can you go to the chat room to continue the conversation?

Comment: @Hans I have used the obvious $\int_0^\infty x^3 e^{-kx} =  k^{-4} 3!$. If you understand that then check the big list of derivations of $\zeta(2) =\pi^2/6$ and try adapting them

Comment: I know what you are doing. Do you then sum $\frac1{k^4}$ over all $k$? If so, I have requested **NOT** to do that in the original question. Do you understand the negation ("NOT") request?

Comment: @Hans Don't be insulting. As I said by direct application of the residue theorem and the elementary $\int_0^\infty x^3 e^{-kx} =  k^{-4} 3!$ we obtain $$\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{|z|=2\pi N+\pi} \frac{z^{-4}}{e^z-1}dz = \frac{f^{(4)}(0)}{4!} +  \frac{2^{-3} \pi^{-4}}{3!} \int_0^\infty x^3 \frac{1-e^{-N x}}{e^x-1}dx$$ and hence $$0 = \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{|z|=2\pi N+\pi} \frac{z^{-4}}{e^z-1}dz = \frac{f^{(4)}(0)}{4!} +  \frac{2^{-3} \pi^{-4}}{3!} \int_0^\infty \frac{x^3}{e^x-1}dx$$ If you don't like it, check the big list

Comment: I am not insulting you. On the contrary, I think you have been condescending. Let's put that aside. You are repeating what you wrote before and not reading my response. I was asking: are you or are you not establishing your first equation using the intermediate step involving the sum $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^4}$? Would you please be so kind as to answer this question with a yes or no?

Comment: @Hans No. Do **you** need it to prove it ?

Comment: Yes, that will be awesome. Please prove it explicitly and in detail, in your answer, **NOT** using the sum.

Comment: @Hans Did you try ? I already gave all the details.

Comment: My contension is that the detail you gave contradicts my requestion in the question. I have edited my question again to make it very explicit. Please review and tell me if you still think your answer satisfies my request.

Comment: @Hans Are you kidding ? I said 3 times that $\frac{1}{3!}\int_0^\infty x^3 e^{-kx} = Res(\frac{z^{-4}}{e^z-1},2i\pi k)$  and hence with the residue theorem $$\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{|z|=2\pi N+\pi} \frac{z^{-4}}{e^z-1}dz = \sum_{k=-N}^N Res(\frac{z^{-4}}{e^z-1},0)= \frac{f^{(4)}(0)}{4!} +  \frac{2^{-3} \pi^{-4}}{3!} \int_0^\infty x^3 \frac{1-e^{-N x}}{e^x-1}dx$$ And if you don't like it, check the [big list](https://www.google.fr/search?q=big+list+proof+zeta(2))

Comment: You are just doing the finite sum then taking the limit. This is just adding details for limit taking in the geometric series and the size of contour. How is it any different from what I said about infnite sum in my question? You can take the limit any time you want. It is guaranteed by the Lesbegue dominant theorem.

Comment: @Hans Yes but read your question, how can you hope something better than $$\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{|z|=N} g(z) dz = C+D\ \int_0^\infty x^3 \frac{1-e^{-N x}}{e^x-1}dx$$ where $C,D$ are known constants and $g$ is a simple meromorphic function converging to $0$ at $\infty$ ? Obviously you can't.

Comment: First, so you do acknowledge now that your method contradicts my request, right? Regarding your new comment, I have to borrow your exclamation, "are you kidding?" ;-P It is easy to find $g$. Let whatever is on the right hand side be $a$. Set $g(z)=\frac az$.

Comment: @Hans It is clear you don't understand the maths involved here and you don't want to learn anything.

Comment: That is rather ironic to read your presumptuous claim which is better applied to you. This is not your first line of pretension. It is amazing that you are not the slightest bit embarrassed that it took you this whole panel of back and forth for you to acknowledge “Yes but…” and realize you have used $\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} u^n = \frac{1-y^N}{1-y}$ just as I have said in my first comment and that contradicts my specific constraint imposed on the solution of the problem. All this time I have been tolerating your condescension.

Comment: Using your own pompous phrase, “it is 100% clear” that you do not comprehend fully what you wrote as your answer and it is highly likely that you simply copied whatever is in that big list of solutions without knowing all the details. Otherwise, how do you ever explain your inability to comprehend the most rudimentary geometric series when it stares right in your face? It is actually quite funny to see you after having finally acknowledged the rudimentary mistake, making up some nonsensical claim with $C$, $D$ and $g$. You cannot even define what “better” is.